# Converting JavaScript Array To JSON Format:JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array like this coming back response from the server:

```
[
    [
        "111",
        1
    ],
    [
        "1010",
        4
    ],
    [
        "111",
        5
    ],
    [
        "1010",
        6
    ],
    [
        "1010",
        7
    ]
]
```

i want to convert it into a JavaScript JSON like this:

```
[
 {
    "branch":  "111",
    "id":1

 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010",
    "id":4
 },
 {
    "branch":  "111",
     "id":5
 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010",
     "id":6
 },
 {
    "branch":  "1010",
     "id":7
 }
]
```

If any one can help it will be much appreciable. Bcs i am new to javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can do this with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

### Solution:

```js
const data = [["111",1],["1010",4],["111",5],["1010",6],["1010",7]];

const res = data.map(([branch,id])=>({branch,id}));

res.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id);

console.log(res);
```